# How to instantiate a dictionary by using for loop (swift)

Tags: swift

```
private var selectedButtonArray = [UIButton]() 
private var buttonStepperDictionaryArray = [NSMutableDictionary]()

func appendToButtonStepperDictionaryArray(ixSelectionItem: IxSelectionItem...){
    for iSelectionItem in selectedButtonArray{
        buttonStepperDictionaryArray.append("buttonDesc":iSelectionItem.button.text,"dsds":iSelectionItem.button.tag)
    }
}
```

The result should look like this:

```
[{"buttonDesc":"abc","buttonTag":1},
 {"buttonDesc":"bcd","buttonTag":2},
 {"buttonDesc":"ddd","buttonTag":3}]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What does your code currently do? Why `NSMutableDictionary`? And you're missing some [] when you try to append

Comment: I am new in programming. i don't know the format to instantiate it by using for loop. could you give  me an example. i am trying to make selectedButtonArray to a dictionary

Comment: The for loop has nothing to do with it, you just aren't creating a dictionary to append and it isn't clear why you seem to want a mutable dictionary. You need to instantiated whatever kind of dictionary you want and append that.

Comment: so how should i change the code in order to get the result like that

Comment: Create a `struct` that holds the `UIButton`, the button description and its tag. Use an array of these structs. A dictionary is the wrong data structure for this.

Comment: can you give me some example of code

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private var selectedButtonArray = [UIButton]()
private var buttonStepperDictionaryArray = [NSMutableDictionary]()

func appendToButtonStepperDictionaryArray(ixSelectionItem: IxSelectionItem){
    for iSelectionItem in selectedButtonArray{
        buttonStepperDictionaryArray.append(["buttonDesc": ixSelectionItem.button.text,"dsds":iSelectionItem.tag])
    }
}
```